# Google Map displays with empty location even with valid api key in flutter when app is launched and works properly when i do multiple hot reload

Tags: android, flutter, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to embed native `android` view of google map in my `flutter` app. I know we already have `google_map_plugin` on `pub.dev` but to improve myself as a developer i am trying to integrate native android code in my flutter app

Here is my dart code

```
const myGoogleMapView = 'myGoogleMapView';

class MyGoogleMapView extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyGoogleMapView({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Platform.isAndroid
        ? const AndroidView(
            viewType: myGoogleMapView,
            layoutDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
            creationParams: null,
            creationParamsCodec: StandardMessageCodec(),
          )
        : const UiKitView(
            viewType: myGoogleMapView,
            layoutDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
            creationParams: null,
            creationParamsCodec: StandardMessageCodec(),
          );

   
  }
}
```

Next on the android side i added my apikey in `manifest` and internet permission as well

In `MainActivity.kt`

```
class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {

override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
    super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)

    flutterEngine
        .platformViewsController
        .registry
        .registerViewFactory("myGoogleMapView", MyGoogleMapViewFactory(this))

}
}
```

Then i created `MyGoogleMapViewFactory` & `MyGoogleMapView`

```
class MyGoogleMapViewFactory(private val activity: FlutterActivity) : PlatformViewFactory(StandardMessageCodec.INSTANCE) {
    override fun create(context: Context, viewId: Int, args: Any?): PlatformView {
        val creationParams = args as Map<String?, Any?>?
        return MyGoogleMapView(context, viewId, creationParams,activity)

    }
}

class MyGoogleMapView(context: Context, id: Int, creationParams: Map<String?, Any?>?,activity: FlutterActivity) :
    PlatformView, OnMapReadyCallback {
    private val mapview: MapView = MapView(context)
    private var loadedCallbackPending = false
    private var mMap: GoogleMap? = null
    private var currentMarker: Marker? = null

    override fun getView(): View {
        return mapview
    }

    override fun dispose() {}

    init {
        val layoutParams: ViewGroup.LayoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        )
        mapview.layoutParams = layoutParams

        mapview.onCreate(null)
        mapview.getMapAsync(this)

    }


    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap
        val myLocation = LatLng(37.7749, -122.4194)
        if (currentMarker != null) {
            currentMarker?.remove()
        }
        currentMarker = mMap?.addMarker(
            MarkerOptions().position(myLocation).title("Marker Title")
        )
        mMap?.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myLocation, 10f))


    }

    private fun invalidateMapIfNeeded() {
        if (mMap == null || loadedCallbackPending) {
            return
        }
        loadedCallbackPending = true
        mMap!!.setOnMapLoadedCallback {
            loadedCallbackPending = false
            postFrameCallback {
                postFrameCallback {
                    mapview.invalidate()
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private fun postFrameCallback(f: Runnable) {
        Choreographer.getInstance().postFrameCallback { f.run() }
    }


}
```

I just see an empty google map with my marker on it. I am 100% sure my apikey is correct as i am using the same one with same package name in my native `android` application & it works fine

I also checked the google map plugin's code on `github` and they had written `invalidateMapIfNeeded` which i copy pasted and tried calling it in different places like `init`, `onMapReady` etc but didn't work for me

Also i tried to use `Hybrid` composition on dart side as well

```
return PlatformViewLink(
      viewType: myGoogleMapView,
      surfaceFactory: (context, controller) {
        return AndroidViewSurface(
          controller: controller as AndroidViewController,
          gestureRecognizers: const <Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>>{},
          hitTestBehavior: PlatformViewHitTestBehavior.opaque,
        );
      },
      onCreatePlatformView: (params) {
        return PlatformViewsService.initSurfaceAndroidView(
          id: params.id,
          viewType: myGoogleMapView,
          layoutDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
          creationParams: null,
          creationParamsCodec: const StandardMessageCodec(),
          onFocus: () {
            params.onFocusChanged(true);
          },
        )
          ..addOnPlatformViewCreatedListener(params.onPlatformViewCreated)
          ..create();
      },
    );
```

but this also does not work. when i try to use simple views like `TextView` or `EditText` from native android side then it works fine. Not sure what is the problem with google map

Logs are [here][1] as i was excedding the text limit

Output

[image]

One more thing i noticed is when i run the app for first time the gooogle map is empty like i showed above but if i keep doing hot reload multiple times the map starts showing up slowly. Check this [video][3] to know more

Comment: Hello, how about in the logcat? Any error or warnings shown? If it's the same API key with your Native app, maybe it had some restrictions that only allows that certain native app? Have you tried creating a new API key? Since it is recommended to use separate keys for separate apps / implementations

Comment: I have tried with different api key as well but same issue. I am pretty sure it is not api key issue but something related to invalidting and requestLayout thing as i was checking the google_map_plugin. I have added my logs here https://gist.github.com/kyadalu1/784bfbd45229060b9d9709d92d0751b0

Comment: Yeah I can see in the logcat you provided that there seems to be no API key issue. Can you show a screenshot of what you see?

Comment: @Yrll I have added it in question

Comment: @Yrll One more thing i noticed is when i run the app for first time the gooogle map is empty like i showed above but if i keep doing hot reload multiple times the map starts showing up slowly. Check video https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/spot-fb6be.appspot.com/o/Screen%20Recording%202023-09-18%20at%2012.29.48%20PM.mov?alt=media&token=46f340c5-a215-4dfa-af47-8cfe30565235  to know more

Comment: Could it be that you just had a slow internet? But in any case, it looks like there was some delay before your map gets the authentication done and show the map. Looking at the image also, it looks like you are still using the legacy renderer, have you tried loading the map with the latest one? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/renderer

Comment: I don't have slow internet. The same code works perfectly fine on native android app. I am using the new renderer. This is my dependency implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0")

Comment: The problem with your code is that you are not calling invalidateMapIfNeeded() in the right place. You should call it in the onMapReady() callback, after you have set the mMap variable.

Comment: @JaspalsinhGohil I already did that. Still it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `mapview.onResume()` in onMapReady. You don't need the invalidation code

Answer (score 0):

This error seems to be related with the Google Maps APi from google console and authorizations. Did you placed the SHa-1 in and restricted the API? I remember geting this kind of error once.

Comment: It works fine in native android app with same and different api key